# React build files working well but is not working in the XAMPP

Tags: reactjs

I created build files in my react project. After I checked it using 'serve -s build'. My build is working correctly. But now i need to run this using XAMPP server. Therefore i Copied build folder and paste it in side the xammp htdocs folder. after i tried to access it from browser. but Index file loaded with empty.

i checked console. please check below image. How i do this using xammp

I checked index file source code in the browser. its said

```
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run `build` folder by only placing it in `xampp/htdocs`, you always need to Node.js server for running react build, as do as you doing before run above command `serve -s build`

Answer (score 0):

Please make it clear
`You copy pasted the contents of the build folder`
or
`You copy pasted the build folder` ?

Cuz I think you copied the build folder whole.

Do a favour and **copy everything in the build folder (not the folder itself) and paste in in htdocs**

I don't think you should be having this in the first place
[image: why the /build]
try running it at root (localhost:60/)

Comment: I copied build folder and paste it to htdocs folder

Comment: Shouldn't react project be running at root ?

Comment: sorry i did not get u

Comment: Do as I said (Forget /build) copy everything in build folder and paste in in htdocs directly (not under any folder). Do not copy the build folder. copy the things in it. Then run the app on localhost:60/